"TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type, a tuple of types, or a union" while Writing to BigQuery table on a Dataflow pipeline using Apache Beam
I am working on a Dataflow pipeline in Pthon using apache-beam==2.57.0 and google-cloud-bigquery==3.26.0 to read data from a Cloud SQL database and write it to a BigQuery table. The script runs into the following error when attempting to write to BigQuery:
| "Write to BigQuery" >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\x\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\apache_beam\io\gcp\bigquery.py", line 2083, in __init__
    self.table_reference = bigquery_tools.parse_table_reference(
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File File "C:\x\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\apache_beam\io\gcp\bigquery_tools.py", line 263, in parse_table_reference
    if isinstance(table, TableReference):
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type, a tuple of types, or a union

Environment:

Python version: 3.11
Apache Beam version: 2.57.0
google-cloud-bigquery version: 3.26.0
Runner: DirectRunner (for local testing)

Details:
I have verified that my versions are compatible based on the setup file from the Apache Beam GitHub repository (google-cloud-bigquery>=2.0.0,<4).
The table_id is formatted as project_id:dataset_id.table_name.
The table schema is defined as a dictionary.
Example:
 table_schema = {
        "fields": [
            {"name": "trip_id", "type": "STRING"},
            {"name": "vehicle_id", "type": "STRING"},
            {"name": "customer_id", "type": "STRING"},
            {"name": "driver_id", "type": "STRING"}
        ]
    }

Issue occurs even when:
schema='trip_id: STRING, vehicle_id: STRING, customer_id: STRING, driver_id: STRING,',

Additionally, I encountered an issue when trying to install apache-beam[gcp] via pip:
$ pip install apache-beam[gcp]
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement google-apitools<0.5.32,>=0.5.31; extra == "gcp" (from apache-beam[gcp]) (from versions: 0.5.32)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for google-apitools<0.5.32,>=0.5.31; extra == "gcp"

I am using a private PyPI repository (https://pjfrog@/...). This may be impacting the installation. I cleared pip cache and tried using --index-url=https://pypi.org/simple to install directly from the public PyPI repository.
Code Snippet:
# Create the Beam pipeline
with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:
    (
        p
            | "Start" >> beam.Create([None]) 
            | "Read from Cloud SQL" >> beam.ParDo(ReadFromCloudSQL()) 
            | "Print results" >> beam.Map(print)  # Print each element to the console
            | "Write to BigQuery" >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                table=table_id,
                schema=table_schema,
                create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_NEVER,
                write_disposition=beam.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND 

             )
    )


Does this give you anything? from apache_beam.io.gcp.internal.clients.bigquery import TableReference. and have you simply tried this example? https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataflow-cookbook/blob/main/Python/bigquery/write_bigquery.py

I was able to resolve this error after updating beam version to 2.59 and installing  apache-beam[gcp].
After disconnecting from VPN, I was able to install this package from PyPi repo.
pip install apache-beam[gcp] --index-url=https://pypi.org/simple
